# Setting UIpanel size from script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, ngui

I am trying to re-create my game using the NGUI plugin for Unity and I like it a lot so far, but am in the mist on this one.

I have an UIPanel called games and I want programmatically to change it size but don't know how to get into the parameters...

I have tried like this, but with no luck:

```
GameObject.Find("Games").UIPanel.size.x = 300;
```

Also tried this, but with no luck:

```
GameObject.Find("Games").GetComponent("UIPanel").clipping.size.x = 300;
```

This doesn't work and I don't know how to do this... Any help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set clipRange property.

```
GameObject.Find("Games").GetComponent("UIPanel").clipRange = new Vector4(x, y, z , w);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of two things.

First is by setting the absolute values of the corners of the UIRect (UIPanel inherits from UIRect)

```
mPanel.localCorners[0].Set(0.5f, 0.5f, 1f); //this is bottom_left corner
```

You can also use worldCorners instead of localCorners.
The other option is to adjust the anchor values, if you panel is anchored.

```
mPanel.leftAnchor.absolute = 200;
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `baseClipRange` manually is not recommended (due to documentation), but you can produce full clip updating by **invoke `clipOffset` setter** (it does the necessary internals).

I did the same, when I wanted to clip a `UIPanel` with a moving `UIWidget`.

```
// Set clipping region to some widget dimension.
panel.baseClipRegion = new Vector4(
    clippingWidget.cachedTransform.localPosition.x,
    clippingWidget.cachedTransform.localPosition.y,
    clippingWidget.width,
    clippingWidget.height
    );

// Invoke culling.
panel.clipOffset += Vector2.one; 
panel.clipOffset -= Vector2.one;
```